# Automount as another user (not logged)

Tags: gnome, udev, automounting, polkit, udisks

When I plug a USB Key on my desktop install of a redhat fork, USB is automounted as /run/media//. I would like that plugged removable device will be automounted for another logged user (not the current desktop one).

Which configuration should I set to do so ? (polkit?, udev?, udisk ?)

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I think that the user who mounts the stick is the one that has a *session* currently has an active *seat* (as shown by `loginctl list-seats`); you can check which sessions are currently active using `loginctl list-sessions`. You will need to start and keep a session active for the mounting user (`loginctl enable-linger`, probably?), and then need to make a seat with a dummy GPU, I guess, to be able to bind the USB devices to that. I think! I'm not sure about any of this, which is why I'm not writing this as an answer.

Comment: If you, however, know the label (or UUID) of the thing you want to mount as the other user, and it doesn't change, then you can just put a `udev` rule in place that does the mounting for you. Generally, all this smells a bit of a XY problem! Can you tell us what you need to achieve is? "Mounting for a different user" is not per se a goal, but seems more like something you want to do for a greater purpose, which we sadly don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I do not know the UUID of key to be mount. But I do kown the uid of user who must access it. My goal is the following:

Comment: Current logged user on desktop session must NOT be able to use any removable device. When a (any) USB Key is plugged an application running as a daemon within another user with specific uid/gid must handle it. I spied this application behavior. It uses glib to handle removable device related event as nautilus would do. I except to use the same default mechanism but "redirect" it to another user. Do you know default automounting rules are defined ?

Comment: udev; that's where you want to always bind USB storage devices to be mounted by the desired user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will study udev more in depth.